# Why a flip a bin before hashing in this script?

Tags: blockchain, php

From [How can I make this PHP merkle root script recursive?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43565/how-can-i-make-this-php-merkle-root-script-recursive)

```
function binFlipByteOrder($string) {
    return implode('', array_reverse(str_split($string, 1)));
}
```

Why a flip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashes are big endian by standard, and most computers use little endian, so it's probably just for convenience. See [Why does the Bitcoin protocol use the little-endian notation?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/why-does-the-bitcoin-protocol-use-the-little-endian-notation)

Comment: Ok thanks you! (I suspected the Lilliputians..)

Comment: haha they are alive and well in Bitcoin... :)

Comment: Of course it's a little big part of Internet (Cohen) and a community story :) So they are well in Bitcoin :)